# Bad named links search and replace

Tags: python, regex, bash, sed, awk

The problem i'm facing is badly named links...
There are few hundred bad links in different files.

So I write bash to replace links

`<a href="../../../external.html?link=http://www.twitter.com">`
`<a href="../../external.html?link=http://www.facebook.com/pages/somepage/">`

`<a href="../external.html?link=http://www.tumblr.com/">`
to direct links like 
    `<a href="http://www.twitter.com>`

I know we have pattern ../ repeating one or more times. Also external.html?link which also should be removed.

How would recommend to do this? awk, sed, maybe python??
Will i need regex?

Thanks for opinions...

Comment: What do you want to do with the links once you find them?

Comment: Just delete them and leave direct link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *could* be a place where regular expressions are the correct solution. You are only searching for text in attributes, and the contents are regular, fitting a pattern.

The following python regular expression would locate these links for you:

```
r'href="((?:\.\./)+external\.html\?link=)([^"]+)"'
```

The pattern we look for is something inside a `href=""` chunk of text, where that 'something' starts with one or more instances of `../`, followed by `external.html?link=`, then followed with any text that does not contain a `"` quote.

The matched text after the equals sign is grouped in group 2 for easy retrieval, group 1 holds the `../../external.html?link=` part.

If all you want to do is remove the `../../external.html?link=` part altogether (so the links point directly to the endpoint instead of going via the redirect page), leave off the first group and do a simple `.sub()` on your HTML files:

```
import re
redirects = re.compile(r'href="(?:\.\./)+external\.html\?link=([^"]+)"')

# ...
redirects.sub(r'href="\1"', somehtmlstring)
```

Note that this could also match any body text (so outside HTML tags), this is not a HTML-aware solution. Chances are there is no such body text though. But if there is, you'll need a full-blown HTML parser like BeautifulSoup or lxml instead.

Comment: Working with a HTML parser is less pain and less error-prone than using any kind of regular expressions - not recommendable.

Comment: Nope, don't agree. The knee-jerk reaction of 'lol, the OP is trying to parse HTML with regular expressions' does not always apply. Sometimes a simple job can be done with RE *provided you understand the tool*.

Comment: i think this is a good use for regexes.  OP isn't constructing or manipulating HTML just a single fixed pattern.

Comment: I really appreciate, thanks, just got it working. One more thing to my todo list regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML parser like BeautifulSoup or lxml.html.

Comment: +1. Bash, sed, awk and regular expressions are [not fit to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1524545) sanely.

Comment: No, but bash, sed, awk and re are fit to parse simple patterns. It may be that a full-blown HTML parser is not needed here; the OP is not trying to match whole tags.

Comment: Yup i'm not parsing whole document. I just want track this specific pattern and delete it. What's all i wanna do. So simpler the better...

Comment: I might suggest learning a proper HTML parser now, on a simple problem, so you understand how it works in the future for more complicated problems.

Comment: We are scaling website by making Wordpress to static website. Everything works ok, but tool generates static content makes those links.